# OpenBUGS Code gives error 'expected a comma' in survival

Tags: openbugs

I am trying to fit a hierarchical model using OpenBUGS, with the following code:

```
model
{
    for (i in 1:N) {
          for (j in 1:M){
# Survival times bounded below by censoring times:
            t[i,j] ~ dweib(r,mu[i,j]) I(cen[i,j],);
            mu[i,j] <- b[i]*exp(beta);
            }
# Random effects:
        b[i] ~dlnorm(mu, tau)
    }
# Priors:
    beta ~ dnorm(0, 0.001);
     tau ~ dgamma(1.0E-3, 1.0E-3);
    r~ dgamma(1, 1.0E-3);
    sigma2<-1/tau
    mu<-(-1)/2*tau
}
```

But, I get the 

error : `'expected a comma'`, and OpenBUGS highlights `tausg` in the `tau`...
what I am doing wrong. 
thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have specified mu in two places - once as `mu[i,j] <- b[i]*exp(beta),` and then later as `mu<-(-1)/2*tau`. You need to change the name of one of them.